# price comparison service, how to effectively use a sitemap file?

Tags: web-crawler, sitemap

Many online shops provide a sitemap file which contains their product information in the form of:

```
...
    <url>
          <loc>http://blabla.com/tbcart/pc/-DOOR-GYM-Full-Body-Exerciser-256p34168.htm</loc>
          <lastmod>2010-11-26</lastmod>
          <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    </url>
...
```

But for an online price comparison service to work, it needs the actual product prices in addition to their URL. Assuming that a typical sitemap for an online shop contains 20'000 URLs, how would you proceed in getting the actual prices for each product ? Is this how the sitemap should be used for getting product prices ?

It is highly likely that, performing 20'000 Http Get requests would cause the online shop to block the IP of the crawler :)

Thanks,

PS - How would this scale ? Like a sitemap with 50'000 links, Let's say one needs to reindex every Sunday, this implies sending 1 request every 2 seconds during the whole day, How can one avoid getting blocked in this situation ?

Comment: That's exactly what web crawlers do. But they typically don't do it on a fixed day, you should build some logic to scan products that are more likely to have changed. For example, Google WebCrawler scans popular sites more often than less popular.

Comment: If you are concerned that the site might filter your requests due to excessive use, you must also be aware that what you propose is in violation of the site's AUP and/or intellectual property rights. If you wish to use these data, contact the site in question and request a copy. Scraping large amounts of copyrighted content without the owner's permission is theft.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to execute the GET against all the URLs and then parse the HTML to pull out the price. You are correct that if you hit a site for all their products they may ban you, so you need to include some clever logic to spread the load so it won't affect the shop too much. And then if you get tricky you can determine if there are some products where the price changes more frequently then you can just re-scan those products' prices.
Also noteworthy is that not all sites supply a sitemap, in which case you have to crawl the site and parse the HTML for product URLs as well (just like search engines do).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to reindex the site every Sunday? There seems to be a lastmod-tag set in your example so you could just crawl the whole website as a base and then check for modified pages the whole week (not just on one day). If a site has been changed, you could recrawl it and then set the delay for the next page on this domain to the value in the robots.txt (if set) or several seconds (5 might already be ok).

However, this only works if the shop owner does change the lastmod-tag when the price has been changed (and not only when he changes description texts). If lastmod is not changed, you have to take Haukman’s approach and measure the average time between changes on the page (if you recrawl a page and the price has not changed, delay the next visit; if it has changed, try it even a bit faster the next time).